# Tomcat7 serving blank pages

Tags: eclipse-luna

I am using Java with Tomcat7 to develop a web application.
I'm a trying to test my services in local using Eclipse built-in environment.
My servlets are working fine but I get blank pages when loading HTML file.

My home page is configured like so in my web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

My ports 8005, 8080 and 8009 are not in used by another application.
I tried switching Tomcat's location in Eclipse properties but nothing changed.

Why is Tomcat serving blank HTML pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: I simply moved all my HTML files under the `WebContent` directory.

`WebContent` appears to be the root directory of Java EE web applications under Eclipse.